# SQL Query Syntax : Using table alias in a count is invalid? Why?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ora-01747

Could someone please explain to me why the following query is invalid?  I'm running this query against an Oracle 10g database.

```
select count(test.*) from my_table test;
```

I get the following error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

*however*, the following two queries are valid.

```
select count(test.column) from my_table test;

select test.* from my_table test;
```

Comment: Because Oracle has gaps in its support for standard SQL.

Comment: @Bill: `MySQL` and `SQL Server` don't support this syntax too.

Comment: @Quassnoi: MySQL does support the syntax (I just tested it with version 5.1.46).  I haven't tested SQL Server.

Comment: @Bill: `CREATE TABLE t_count (id INT NOT NULL); SELECT COUNT(t_count.*) FROM t_count;`. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM t_count' at line 1

Comment: @Bill Karwin: `SELECT COUNT(test.*) FROM MY_TABLE test` fails - "Incorrect syntax near '*'" on SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Aha, you are correct. I retract my statement.

Comment: Are you trying to get a count of records which have at least one non-null value in a column? In Oracle, to do this you'll have to use something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE COALESCE(colA, colB, colC, colD, etc) IS NOT NULL` - this is not normally useful, of course, since a table with all columns `NULL`able is usually the sign of poor design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`COUNT(expression)`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm#i82697) will count all rows where `expression` is not null. `COUNT(*)` is an exception, it returns the number of rows: `*` is not an alias for `my_table.*`.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, `Count(Table.*)` is not officially supported in the SQL specification. Only `Count(*)` (count all rows returned) and `Count(Table.ColumnName)` (count all non-null values in the given column). So, even if the DBMS supported it, I would recommend against using it.`

Comment: For oracle, the 'reason' is that count() requires an expression, whereas [table.]* is not an expression, but a part of syntax offered as part of a SELECT as an alternative to an expression.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax only works in `PostgreSQL` and only because it has a record datatype (for which `test.*` is a meaningful expression).

Just use `COUNT(*)`.

This query:

```
select count(test.column) from my_table test;
```

will return you the number of records for which `test.column` is not `NULL`.

This query:

```
select test.* from my_table test;
```

will just return you all records from `my_table`.

`COUNT` as such is probably the only aggregate that makes sense without parameters, and using an expression like `COUNT(*)` is just a way to call a function without providing any actual parameters to it.

Comment: There's a major difference between COUNT(*) and COUNT(column): the former counts all rows; the latter counts the rows where the column value is NOT NULL.  They are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

You might reasonably want to find the number of records where test.column is not NULL if you are doing an outer join.  As every table should have a PK (which is not null) you should be able to count the rows like that if you want:

```
select count(y.pk)
from x
left outer join y on y.pk = x.ck
```

COUNT(*) is no good here because the outer join is creating a null row for the table that is deficient in information.